# How to correctly bulk insert in MariaDB

Tags: laravel, mariadb

**Problem background:** I am trying to do a bulk insert of many insert statements in laravel using `DB::unprepared` function by constructing and executing a procedure in MariaDB:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure_name;
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
        /* (996 more insert statements) */
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
    END;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
        /* (996 more insert statements) */
        INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
    END;
    /* many more such BEGIN END inserts */
END // 
DELIMITER ;
CALL procedure_name;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure_name;
```

Each inner BEGIN ... END pair has 1000 insert statements. In a procedure there can be many (a lot more than 20) such BEGIN ... END pairs.

I am using and executing a procedure because this is the only way I got bulk insert to work on test data. I was referencing [this MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/#inserting-data-with-insert-statements). When inserting real data that produces more than 100 insert statements I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO items (vin, destination, transport_id, port_of_origi...' at line 2
```

I searched for some answers like [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151888/stored-procedure-error-1064?newreg=f593965fa10246758ec03c54cdf8990c).

I also tried to omit DELIMITER, without success.

Comment: You have `BEGIN BEGIN`, doesn't look right to me

Comment: We tried without outer BEGIN and it does not work either.

Comment: why don't you use eloquent or query builder?

Comment: "this is the only way I got bulk insert to work" - which ways have you tried so far?

Comment: @YusufGiovanno i will try using query builder and post an update

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I tried to execute the query exactly as described in [this MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/#using-big-transactions), so without any procedures. But this did not work. I think because BEGIN END statements can not be used in such way. So that is why I used procedures.

Answer (score 0):

```
    INSERT INTO table_name (param1, param2, ...)
        VALUES
            (val1, val2, ...),
            (val1, val2, ...),
            ... /* (997 more insert statements) */
            (val1, val2, ...);
```

This does not need to be in a stored Proc.  But if it is, you need to use a pair of `DELIMITER` statements when defining the SP.

1000 rows is a good number.  More than 1K might get into various limits or allocation issues.  Less than 1K would be slightly slower.  Roughly speaking, 10 units of overhead for `INSERT`, 1 unit of processing time per row.  So 1K rows is 99% of the theoretical limit.

If you `autocommit=ON` and don't have transactions around the set of them, this also feeds into the efficiency.  But a crash will stop after some multiple of 1K rows.

Insert less than 1K rows if the text string is bigger than `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: Is there a limit on how many value lines `(val1, val2, ...),` can be in one insert? As far as I know there is no limit. I will try your suggestion as well and post an update.

Comment: @mikrovalovna - I said a little more.

Comment: The entire insert length can't exceed https://mariadb.com/docs/server/ref/mdb/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/